# Adding a color to tcl prompt1 causes the history to be displayed incorrectly

Tags: tcl, readline

First I added the color for the tcl prompt

```
proc ::tclreadline::prompt1 {} {
    return "\033\[31m Test \033\[0m" 
}
```

Then run a long command

```
 Test 11111111111111111111
invalid command name "11111111111111111111"
while evaluating 11111111111111111111
 Test 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
invalid command name "22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
while evaluating 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

Then bring up the history command by using the ↑ key and click twice and execute

```
 Test 22222222211111111111111111111
invalid command name "11111111111111111111"
while evaluating 11111111111111111111
```

I don't know why 222222 appears before 111111, but it doesn't actually count as part of the execution command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `tclreadline`](https://tclreadline.sourceforge.net/) says:

> Note that non-printable control characters as color control characters must be enclosed in literal ctrl-a / ctrl-b to tell readline the length of the printable prompt.

That means that you need to add `\001` (the character that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> generates before the non-printable control code sequence, and `\002` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) after, like this:

```
proc ::tclreadline::prompt1 {} {
    return "\001\033\[31m\002 Test \001\033\[0m\002" 
}
```

That's a bit messy! Let's do a slightly neater version:

```
proc escape {str} {
    return "\001\033\[$str\002"
}

proc ::tclreadline::prompt1 {} {
    return "[escape 31m] Test [escape 0m]" 
}
```

Comment: Note that there's something equivalent if you set coloured prompts in shells; the readline library really does need to know which parts of the prompt string don't move the cursor...